# Start and stop minecraft (java process) via php

Tags: java, php, linux, process, minecraft

OK, let me try again.  :-)

If I try:

```
<?php
exec("java -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.4.2-R0.2.jar -o true");
?>
```

The web page never returns.  I believe it is because the CGI is waiting for the process to complete, which of course it never does because it is a server.

I try this locally and if I put the same command in the terminal it runs as expected so I know there is no problem with the command line.

So...the question is:

1) does exec block until the process completes?
2) if no, what is happening here, if yes, how can I change that behavior?

=============================================================

So this is really a generic question, but I have included to the specific environment which might help to explain why I am trying to do this.  This is all on LINUX.

I want to launch a Java process remotely from a PHP page.  The trick of course is that the process will keep running and I want to the PHP page complete once the process has successfully launched.

So, first how do I do that?  I've tried a number of things I've read and can't get them to work.

The second part is a little more tricky.  The way you stop the minecraft server, is in the terminal you type "Stop".  And of course you can enter other commands there to do other things...its just reading from stdin.

If I want to stop it, or send it other commands, I need to connect to stdin from a PHP script and send it text or something.

When I launch the java process, do I connect stdin to a file and then from future PHP scripts write to the file?  I don't know.

Just give me a few pointers on the right approach and will try them.  I'll let you know if they work or if I have more detailed questions.

Thanks!

Comment: exec('java command line'); don't say 'I have tried something' with out giving us the exact code you tried.

Comment: PHP in its usual deployment model (one Apache process per request) might be a terrible choice of language for this. I'd pick... anything else, really, as long as it lets you keep your web server process running with a reference to the Minecraft server subprocess.

Comment: Also, this question is a little too broad. It's obvious there's several steps involved in doing what you want, you should research (then ask questions about) implementing those specific steps. ("How do I launch a subprocess from PHP?", "How do I write to the stdin of an arbitrary other process from PHP?". (Or about handling long-running tasks in PHP.)

Answer (score 2):

In php you can use the function exec();
i.e.:

```
<?php
    if($method == "start"){
        exec("java -jar minecraft_server.jar");
    }else if($method == "stop"){
        exec("pkill java");
    }
?>
```

I am not familiar with the exact commands for Minecraft, but this is the theory behind it.

**EDIT**

Have you ever used the program '[screen](http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=s/screen)'?

Create a new detached screen running the Minecraft Server using the following command:

```
screen -dmS Minecraft /home/username/minecraft/launch.sh
```

This will create a new screen named Minecraft, and execute launch.sh, the script that comes with the minecraft server. Thiss will all now run in the background, and not keep a shell occupied.

To send commands to this running screen, you can then use:

```
screen -S Minecraft -X stuff $'stop\n'
```

To send a stop command.

Comment: pkill will kill every `java` process, not just the one started by the PHP script.

Comment: should be easy to get the pid, especially if you started the process with php.

Comment: As stated, the theory is using exec(); I am not familiar with all of the Minecraft commands.